# file:/// path image from SD-Card not showing in ionic cordova

Tags: angularjs, image, cordova, ionic-framework

I have **downloaded image using $cordovaFileTransfer plugin** and stored them **in cordova.file.externalDirectory**.. stored its path in sqlite local database.

When I set that **image's path in image "ng-src" using ng-repeat**.. **images are not showing up**.. I can see 'em in chrome "Inspect Element" that the path is actually having image in there, but somehow its not previewing.

image path which I am getting is something like this:
**file:///storage/sdcard0/appify/imgs/DSC_0124_1443159471.jpg**

but, image not rendering

Any help on this?

Thank you

Comment: have you given permission to access the file system?

Comment: you are checking app in device or in chrome? if you store image in sdcard so how it is work with chrome and how you inspect element in device?

Answer (score 2):

So a couple of things to look at:

1. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files

You may want to look into `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory`

Also, the plugin doc reads:

> For backwards compatibility, the resolveLocalFileSystemURL() method will accept a device-absolute-path, and will return an Entry object corresponding to it, as long as that file exists within either the TEMPORARY or PERSISTENT filesystems.
>
> This has particularly been an issue with the File-Transfer plugin, which previously used device-absolute-paths (and can still accept them). It has been updated to work correctly with FileSystem URLs, so replacing entry.fullPath with entry.toURL() should resolve any issues getting that plugin to work with files on the device.

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Have you tried reading the file in?

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
   fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
         // set source here using result
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });
});
```

Comment: I actually sorted it out.. using cordova's whitelist plugin.. Thanks a lot though